# openldap sizelimit. Can't receive more than 500 entries

Tags: ldap, openldap, query

I can't receive more than 500 entries, when I query my openldap-server.

Although I made the following changes:

**slapd.conf**

```
    # This is the main slapd configuration file. See slapd.conf(5) for more
    # info on the configuration options.

    #######################################################################
    # Global Directives:       
    .....

     # The maximum number of entries that is returned for a search operation
    sizelimit 10000
```

**ldap.conf**

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

SIZELIMIT       10000
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

After restartin my machine, and query the following command:

```
ldapsearch -x -h localhost -b "dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX"
```

I receive:

```
# search result
search: 2
result: 4 Size limit exceeded

# numResponses: 501
# numEntries: 500
```

Did I miss some necessary changes?

Comment: Can you run a `ldapsearch -x -h localhost -z 0 -b "dc=example,dc=org"`? If you receive a size limit you know it is enforced by the server.

Comment: Tried this bevore. I reveice a sizelimit. So how can I fix this ?:(

Comment: Can you confirm you used the `-z 0` switch?

Comment: Yes even with `-z 0`in the command, I receive a sizelimit.

Comment: So it has to do with server settings. Please control you don't have another `sizelimit` directive in database section of `slapd.conf`.

Comment: So, how did you solve it in the end? I'm trying it in slapd.conf with sizelimit <numberOfMaxResult>. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OpenLDAP search limit can be set at server side or client side.

**1. Server side in database section of slapd.conf (old style
    configuration deprecated but steel usable) or cn=config
    (recommended)**

**Globally by database:**

***slapd.conf***

```
sizelimit <numberOfMaxResult>
```

***cn=config***

```
olcSizeLimit: <numberOfMaxResult>
```

This parameter is not mandatory, default is **500**.

**Per user:**

***slapd.conf***

```
limits <Who> size=<numberOfMaxResult>
```

***cn=config***

```
olcLimits: <Who> size=<numberOfMaxResult>
```

***In all cases***

*Who* may be :

`*` : all

`anonymous` : not connected user

`users` : all connected users

`dn.exact="cn=xxxx,ou=people...` : one user

`group/groupOfNames/member="cn=managers,ou=groups...`: group of users

*numberOfMaxResult* may be:

`unlimited` : unlimited size, it's a very bad idea to use this configuration in production

`number (like 300)`: number of max result records.

If both globally and per user limit size are done, **per user limit is applied**.

**2. Client side**

***in ldap.conf client configuration file:***

```
SIZELIMIT <numberOfMaxResult>
```

***Request parameter***

`ldapsearch -z 10 ...` limit result to 10

All client API should provide such parameter.

If both server side and client side limit size are done, **The smallest number is applied**.

This is a **short** summary, for further informations in this topic:

```
man slapd.conf
man slapd-config
```

[Limits configuration in OpenLDAP Administrator's guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/limits.html).

Comment: but this guy "cn=config" is a directory, so how to add there this param?